# move to next page on userform multipage excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i have 5 pages in multipage userform.

if the next button enabled, which it can be clicked by user then it should move to next hidden page, i always got an error "Object Required" it drives me crazy.

```
Private Sub btnGenerate_Click()
iPageNo = MultiPage1.Value + 1
MultiPage1.Pages(iPageNo).Visible = True
MultiPage1.Value = iPageNo
End Sub
```

that code seems doesnt work for me, any help would be appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which line is causing the error when you step thru?

Ensure there are enough existing pages. Also, has the name of the MultiPage object changed?

This code below tested working (2 Pages in MultiPage1, Page2 set hidden):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim iNextPage As Long
    With Me.MultiPage1
        iNextPage = .Value + 1
        If iNextPage < .Pages.Count Then
            .Pages(iNextPage).Visible = True
            .Value = iNextPage
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i just miss spelled the MultiPage1. it should be multipage, my bad :D